# Return a NULL value if no record is found

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle10g

Please help me to achieve the below sceanario.

```
select * from pmdl;

PROPERTY_NAME      VALUE
------------- ----------
profile             1010
```

---

```
select (select value from pmdl where property_name='profile') as value from dual;
```

-->> I am getting 1010 value

select * from pmdl;
no rows selected

```
select (select value from pmdl where property_name='profile') as value from dual;
```

-->> If record doesn't exist the i am getting NULL values.

The same thing i have to achive in multiple records.

```
PROPERTY_NAME      VALUE
------------- ----------
profile             1010 
profile             1020 

select (select value from pmdl where property_name='profile') as value from dual;
```

As i am getting below error due to returning multiple records.

> ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row
>   01427. 00000 -  "single-row subquery returns more than one row"
>   *Cause:
>   *Action:

How to retrive multiple records.

Comment: What result do you want?

Comment: please explain properly for better answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this way:

```
select value from pmdl where property_name='profile'
union
select max(value) from pmdl where property_name='profile'
```

If `pmdl` doesn';t have records second query will return null.

If 1st query returns some data than `union` will remove duplicates from 2nd query.

Comment: That subquery will always return exactly one row, so it does not need to be a subquery -- "select max(value) from pmdl where property_name='profile'" will do.

Comment: Thanks for your responses.. But i need all the values and unless rows selected it should return null value.. Any other way to achieve this

Comment: i am completely new to this... Any other way to achieve this in pl/sql

Comment: "But i need all the values and unless rows selected it should return null value" -- update your question with the result that you'd like to get.

Comment: If i use select value from pmdl where property_name='profile' then i would not get NULL value if table doesn't have records....

Comment: ... and don't forget to provide your updates in the question, not in comments.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example where the first SELECT in the UNION is to return something. If it doesn't then the 2nd SELECT will bring back NULLs. The outer SELECT forces only ONE of the rows to come back. You are gauranteed a row every time.

```
SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES tbl1.*
FROM (SELECT TOP 1 tnok1.TETNokCommID, tnok1.TETID, tnok1.LastSentDate
      FROM tblTETNOKcomms AS tnok1
      WHERE tnok1.TETID = 39
      UNION
      SELECT NULL, NULL, NULL) AS tbl1
ORDER BY 3 DESC
```